# knex migration affect nothing on postgres database created with docker

Tags: typescript, docker, knex.js

Created a postgres container on docker,
mounted the basic setup for `knex migration: lateset`
but the database don't receive the migration.

Knex version: latest
OS:Ubuntu 18.04

don't see to be an issue at all,
but I don't know why it doesn't updating the database in postgres, on my docker container.

How can I migrate in the simplest way, using a docker container to connect my postgres, and use knex to migrate to it?

OUTPUT when I do `sudo yarn knex migrate:latest`

```
juliano@pc:~/Desktop/TDD-typescript-backend-ObjectionJs$ sudo yarn knex migrate: latestyarn run v1.22.0
$ /home/juliano/Desktop/TDD-typescript-backend-ObjectionJs/node_modules/.bin/knex migrate: latest
Requiring external module ts-node/register
Done in 0.67s.
```

my knexfile.ts:

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? '.env.test' : '.env'
})

module.exports = {
  client: 'postgresql',
  connection: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    options: {
      port: process.env.DB_PORT
    }
  }
}
```

my .env:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=docker
DB_NAME=database
DB_PORT=5432
```

my migration:

```
const tableName = 'users'

// TYPE KNEX AND TABLE? 

exports.up = function (knex:any) {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable(tableName, (table:any) => {

      table.increments('id').primary()

      table.string('name')

      table.string('email')

      table.string('password_hash')

      table.date('created_at')

      table.date('updated_at')
    })
}

exports.down = function (knex:any) {
  return knex.schema
    .dropTable('users')
}
```

my docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8e552f8788b1        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   database
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure, try to add extension for typescript to your knexfile.

```
module.exports = {
  client: 'pg',
  migrations: {
    extension: 'ts'
  }
};
```

You could also add some debug prints to your knexfile and migration to make sure that some code in those are actually executed.

To verify that your connection parameters work you can write test.ts:

```
const config = require('knexfile');
const knex = require('knex')(config);

knex.select(1)
  .then(() => console.log('Connection works'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Connection failure', err));
```